# Can I configure pass to always use pinentry-curses?

Tags: fedora, terminal, konsole, pinentry

I use pinentry-qt most of the time, but in the specific case that I'm using pass, I would like to use pinentry-curses because of the faster startup time.

Is there a way that I can configure pass to always call pinentry-curses, while keeping pinentry-qt the system default?

The system is Fedora with KDE.

This seems closely related but I don't know enough to apply it to pass: [Change pinentry program temporarily with gpg-agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236746/3056)

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from [the question you linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236746/3056):

1. Create a wrapper script for `pinentry` (`~/bin/pinentry-wrapper`):

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   #
   # Defaults to Qt, with a choice of curses for selected programs
   # PINENTRY_USER_DATA is a GnuPG defined variable (see man gpg)

   case "$PINENTRY_USER_DATA" in
       curses)
           exec /usr/bin/pinentry-curses "$@"
           ;;
       *)
           exec /usr/bin/pinentry-qt "$@"
           ;;
   esac
   ```
2. Make the script executable:

   ```
   $ chmod u+x ~/bin/pinentry-wrapper
   ```
3. Instruct GnuGP to use your version of `pinentry` (`~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`):

   ```
   pinentry-program /home/neftas/bin/pinentry-wrapper
   ```
4. Restart the `gpg-agent`:

   ```
   $ pkill -HUP gpg-agent
   ```
5. Create a wrapper script for `pass` (`~/bin/pass`):

   ```bsh
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   PINENTRY_USER_DATA=curses /usr/bin/pass "$@"
   ```
6. Make executable:

   ```
   $ chmod u+x ~/bin/pass
   ```
7. Make sure `~/bin` is searched first in your `PATH` (put this in your `.bashrc`):

   ```
   $ export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
   ```
8. Check your work:

   ```
   $ command -v pass
   /home/neftas/bin/pass
   ```

All of these scripts were written on Arch Linux, so the locations may be
different on your distro.

Comment: The second wrapper seems unnecessary. At least I only wanted curses when working from a shell, so followed steps 1-4. here then simply added `PINENTRY_USER_DATA=curses` to my `~/.bashrc`|`.zshrc`.